# Proving that the language of regular expressions is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

**Prove that the language consisting of all valid regular expressions is not regular.**

I am approaching this using the Myhill-Nerode Theorem as follows:

I am trying to find a pairwise distinguishable set. I feel that the proof will have to do largely with bracket expansions leading to an invalid string.

So I thought I would could choose a set like $\left(\left(0^{star}\right)^{star}\right)^n$, which is a valid regular expression, and expand it continuously to show that the resulting strings are invalid regular expressions. But I am struggling to figure out how exactly to do this.

If anyone can tell me what a good string to choose would be and how I should go about the proof, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What are valid regular expressions for you? There are several different definitions around.

Comment: The main idea is that regular languages cannot balance parentheses.